# What is the difference between running a quick start version of hyperledger iroha and building iroha?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

The documentation provided from the site [https://iroha.readthedocs.io](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/)

highlight two different sections titled as Building Iroha and Quick Start Guide (which runs an example test version of Hyperledger Iroha). If any experts here could explain me on the difference between these two, I would be thankful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Start Guide** provides instructions how to run iroha on docker - it is fastest and easiest way.
On the other hand building iroha from scratch is not really complicated, because we need just to copy few commands, and almost all dependencies would be downloaded automatically by vpkg, or with cmake.

**About other differences:**

1. When you use docker's image:
   It is faster to set up, it is harder to make mistake and is more probably than docker's version is fully working.
2. When you build from scratch: You need to read more, find dependencies (there are listed for debian-based linuxes, but for Manjaro you need to find by your own). You also need to wait longer. And what is most important - you are not sure that Your version would work, or even compile (if something is changed in dependence libraries).

Personally despite all those disadvantages I prefer to build manually, because I prefer to compile on my system without extra layer like docker.